# stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString not returning a value

Tags: javascript, macos, swift

In a previous iOS project in objc I was extracting a string from a `UIWebview` with

`NSString*cableType = [toWeb stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('cableType').value"]`

Now i'm trying to do the same in  an OSX app with `WebView` using Swift

```
var cableType = toWeb.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.getElementById('cableType').value")

        if let returnedCableTypeString = cableType {
            println("Cable Type = \(returnedCableTypeString)")
        }
```

My log always returns nothing for the interpolated value `Cable Type =`

Adding an an `else` statement also returns the same

`toWeb` is a `WebView` with a locally loaded `html` file

Comment: Its about what the title says, string not returning a value, not interploation

Comment: Is cableType `nil` or `""` after running? If it is `nil` then it is likely the element does not exist, if it is an empty string then it is likely the value evaluates to .. the empty string.

Comment: Maybe that is the (legitimate) value extracted? That is, does it correctly return the evaluation of `"1 + 2"`, etc?

Comment: And here in lies the problem, its extracting `""` however there is a value there and the `ElementById` is correct

Comment: Can you get a different value (not from a field)? If you get back `""` then that is what is in the DOM when it was run. The previous comments are to aide with self-verification/focus of the issue. Once it is concluded that gB..S works (other values, etc) then it's accepting that the result *is* what it is and exploring it from there. For example, try: `"'>>' + document.getElementById('cableType').value + '<<'"`

Comment: No same value when not extracting from a field`""` `DOM`???

Comment: "Maybe the element has no value". See the update to the last comment for the logical process of narrowing down the problem.

Comment: The process of narrowing down was done before posting the question.  With the above code NO values can be obtained for other fields, also when checking on a non field element.

Comment: Then the question fails to show that and is not a minimal failing case. A trivial case would be to show that gB..S fails to return a value of a simple JS literal value, and shows that it is not related to the output.

Comment: Ok you got me...moving on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing `("document.getElementById('cableType').value")`

to `("document.getElementsByName('cableType').item(0).value")`

has done it

Comment: I've got the exact same problem with a locally loaded file, except this is just a basic function call supposed to show an alert. Any ideas what is causing it?